# Multipage pdf pages matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, ipython, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to execute this exact code [multipage pdf](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html), copy %paste on Ipython, ubuntu14.04, python 2.7.6

I get the following error though

```
RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
'lp'
```

Full traceback

```
sh: 1: latex: not found
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e46ddc0d5d7d> in <module>()
     19     plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), 'b-')
     20     plt.title('Page Two')
---> 21     pdf.savefig()
     22     plt.close()
     23 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.pyc in savefig(self, figure, **kwargs)
   2439             else:
   2440                 figureManager.canvas.figure.savefig(self, format='pdf',
-> 2441                                                     **kwargs)
   2442 
   2443     def get_pagecount(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in savefig(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1474             self.set_frameon(frameon)
   1475 
-> 1476         self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
   1477 
   1478         if frameon:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.pyc in print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)
    159 
    160     def print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 161         FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)
    162         self.draw()
    163 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2209                 orientation=orientation,
   2210                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2211                 **kwargs)
   2212         finally:
   2213             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.pyc in print_pdf(self, filename, **kwargs)
   2483                 RendererPdf(file, image_dpi),
   2484                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore)
-> 2485             self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2486             renderer.finalize()
   2487         finally:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1083         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1084         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1085             func(*args)
   1086 
   1087         renderer.close_group('figure')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2108 
   2109         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2110             a.draw(renderer)
   2111 
   2112         renderer.close_group('axes')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1114         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1115         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
-> 1116                                                                 renderer)
   1117 
   1118         for tick in ticks_to_draw:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1063         for tick in ticks:
   1064             if tick.label1On and tick.label1.get_visible():
-> 1065                 extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1066                 ticklabelBoxes.append(extent)
   1067             if tick.label2On and tick.label2.get_visible():

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    796             raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
    797 
--> 798         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    799         x, y = self.get_position()
    800         x, y = self.get_transform().transform_point((x, y))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    309         tmp, lp_h, lp_bl = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent('lp',
    310                                                          self._fontproperties,
--> 311                                                          ismath=False)
    312         offsety = (lp_h - lp_bl) * self._linespacing
    313 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
   2042             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
   2043             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(s, fontsize,
-> 2044                                                                renderer=self)
   2045             return w, h, d
   2046 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    668         else:
    669             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
--> 670             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    671             dvi = dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction)
    672             try:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    415                      'string:\n%s\nHere is the full report generated by '
    416                      'LaTeX: \n\n' % repr(tex.encode('unicode_escape')) +
--> 417                      report))
    418             else:
    419                 mpl.verbose.report(report, 'debug')
```

Any guess what is wrong with this runtime error?
Since I actually can import rc from matplotlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone is in the same situation I am posting the answer,
apparently latex was installed but matplotlib coudn't figure out the path,
I rebuilt all the environnement as follows:

Updating deb repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This outputs latex reports on ipython

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Finally rebuild all

```
sudo apt-get install dvipng
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```